# Blender export to OBJ and load in Three.js, mesh normals and faces wrong

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I exported my blender model, to OBJ and loaded it to Three.js.

- For the wheels the normals seem to be facing inwards.
- For the track, only mesh appears and does not appear to be mapped correctly.

I reimported the OBJ in blender, and it seems to be displaying correctly, so it seems to be a problem in Three.js.

[Image in blender showing the normals of the wheels are correct, and the track appears correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/125cR.png)

[Codepen of the Three.js code, and OBJ model is here](https://codepen.io/shahrin14/pen/VzvPdB)

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xcc8729 });

//Loader for the model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var geometry = loader.parse(getObjFileAsString());
geometry.position.set(0, 0, 0);
geometry.castShadow = true;
geometry.receiveShadow = true;
geometry.traverse(child => {
  if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
    child.material = material;
  }
});
scene.add(geometry);
```

Do I need to remodel the wheels and track? Or is there a way to fix it in Three.js?

Comment: is the scale of your wheels by chance negative?
can you share your blender file?

Answer (score 0):

the question is why was the export to obj flipping the face normals?

my only guess is that you have a negative scale on your objects. Therefore you have to apply scale and rotation `shift-a` shortcut. Then you should double check if your normals still face outwards. See my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81543/baked-textures-dont-look-like-render/85051#85051).

in Three.js you can also solve flipped normals by playing with your `material.side` value
there is double sided, back and front. [source](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material)

```
node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Comment: Somehow even when I created new cylinders it had the same problem. Apparently only when I changed the "Cap Fill Type" from "Ngon" to "Triangle Fan" did it export to OBJ properly.

That solves my cylinder issue.

For the tracks, I still the problem above. 
I modeled the tracks by creating a cylinder, removing the cap faces .. then extruding the outer faces. 

What would be the best way to model this and have it be exported correctly?